# Memory efficient massive http requests

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I need to do an unlimited HTTP requests from a web API one after another and make it work efficiently and quite fast. (I need it for a utility so it should work no matter how many time im using it, also it should be able to be used on a web server(people use at the same time))
right now I'm using a threading with a queue but after a while of doing it I'm getting errors like:

'**cant start a new thread**'

'**MemoryError**'

or it may work a bit, but pretty slow.

this is a part of my code:

```
concurrent = 25
q = Queue(concurrent * 2)
for i in range(concurrent):
    t = Thread(target=receiveJson)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
for url in get_urls():
    q.put(url.strip())
q.join()
```

*get_urls() is a simple function that returns a list of urls(unknown length)

this is my recieveJson(thread target):

```
def receiveJson():
    while True:
        url = q.get()

        res = request.get(url).json()

        q.task_done()
```

Comment: "after a while" how long is a while?

Comment: is the first code block called many times? you are not waiting for the threads to complete, nor do they have a way to do so. so you may be spinning up threads indefinitely.

Comment: The first code block called every time a user press a button, after a while means if a user presses that button about 5 times the 6th time yields an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from your `Thread`s never ending, notice that there is no exit condition in your `receiveJson` function. The simplest way to signal it should end is usually by enqueuing `None`:

```py
def receiveJson():
    while True:
        url = q.get()
        if url is None:  # Exit condition allows thread to complete
            q.task_done()
            break

        res = request.get(url).json()
        q.task_done()
```

and then you can change the other code as follows:

```py
concurrent = 25
q = Queue(concurrent * 2)
for i in range(concurrent):
    t = Thread(target=receiveJson)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
for url in get_urls():
    q.put(url.strip())
for i in range(concurrent):
    q.put(None)  # Add a None for each thread to be able to get and complete
q.join()
```

There are other ways of doing this, but this is the how to do it with the least amount of change to your code. If this is happening often, it might be worth looking into the [concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) class to avoid the cost of opening threads very often.